# Compiling PowerBuilder application v12.1 Build 6518 and OLE object

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ole, powerbuilder

Problem compiling **PowerBuilder application v12.1 Build 6518**

Several developers are working on this application using **SVN** (client **CollabNet V1.6.16-1**, and **TortoiseSVN V1.6.15 PBSCCProxy 02/01/78**)
This application contains a window that contains "**OLE control**".
The OLE control in its current version is present on this window for 6 months (after migration)
and functions of this control are routinely called to launch the application.

The OLE control is registered on all development workstations (via the `[Regsvr32 AgentLink.dll]`).
The control for this DLL is referenced by Windows,
Indeed, to check, you can recreate this by inserting control over any window, it is present in the list proposed by PB
(Although it disappears from the list after unsubscribing via control of `[Regsvr32 / u AgentLink.dll]`
and reappears after re well over `[Regsvr32 AgentLink.dll]`)

On a workstation (**Windows 7 Pro 32 bit SP1**), the execution of this application in PB and the executable work properly.
On another extension (**Windows 7 Pro 32 bit SP1** too), after recovery sources updates,
Execution in PB and by the standalone generated executable generate the following error message:

```
PowerBuilder Application Execution Error (R0039)
Application terminated.
Error: Error Accessing external object property agentproxy at line 88 in open event of object w_hermes_toolbar.
```

The error occurs on the first call of a function of the OLE object.

After research, an **OLE object** placed on a window generates at the end of the export file of this window a binary section

```
[Start of PowerBuilder Binary Data Section: Do NOT Edit]
```

(This binary section is not visible during an "**Edit Source**")
SVN retransmits this binary section correctly in `.srw` files of the `WorkingCopy`.

By cons, on the computer where the application does not work, an export of the window generates a. Srw with a completely different binary section.
If we replace this binary section corrupted by the one present in the `.srw` file of the **SVN WorkingCopy** and we re-import this modified file in the library (after a **CheckOut**), then the application works again correctly.

This binary section is corrupted on certain items,
either by **PBSCCProxy** (the version of the WorkingCopy contains the right binary section)
either by **PowerBuilder**.
The Regenerate and FullBuild did not changed anything.
The problem is identical in standalone execution or in PB.
Development computers are identical in windows, PB and SVN versions.
**PBSCCProxy versions (2.1.78)** were also identical,
updated with version **2.1.80** after the appearance of the problem (to get the log **PBSCC** implemented in this version)

The problem appeared "suddenly". The application and the generated executable worked perfectly up the compilation of **14.30 (2.30pm)**,
and no longer worked after compiling at **16.00 (4.00pm)** (changes each time were generated on another computer and retrieved via **SVN**).
As far as we know no changes or updates took place in windows between **14:30** and **16:00**.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This section will represent the binary version of the OLE control from the workstation that last edited the object/window.

Ensure that ALL development workstations, including any dedicated build machines, all have the current and correct version of the OLE control installed and registered.

Comment: We have checked and searched on each development workstation all files "AgentLink.dll".
Only the right version is present.

The dll is in the directory C: \ Windows \ system32.

We also unsubscribed then reinstated this dll with regsvr32.

All this did not solve the problem.

I noticed that adding a comment line binary amended this section.
In your opinion is this normal (although the application still works)?